# Order transaction amount

Tags: shopware, shopware6

In Shopware one can have multiple order transactions for an order. An `order_transaction` contains an amount which looks as follows;

```
{
  "quantity": 1,
  "taxRules": [
    {
      "taxRate": 22.0,
      "extensions": [
        
      ],
      "percentage": 100.0
    }
  ],
  "listPrice": null,
  "unitPrice": 12.0,
  "totalPrice": 12.0,
  "referencePrice": null,
  "calculatedTaxes": [
    {
      "tax": 2.16,
      "price": 12.0,
      "taxRate": 22.0,
      "extensions": [
        
      ]
    }
  ],
  "regulationPrice": null
}
```

What is the difference between the `unitPrice` and `totalPrice`?
What's the use of the `quantity` field?
There's documentation about [Payments in Shopware](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/commerce/checkout-concept/payments) but doesn't say any details about the amount field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it short:
`unitPrice = totalPrice / quantity`

In the context of transactions the `quantity` field isn't really used though. A line item of a cart may have a quantity greater than 1 though and that's where the prices of the unit and the total price of the position may differ. Still, for reasons of conformity, all price fields use a common object structure, which will include all of these fields, even if they may not be fully utilized.

Answer (score 0):

The `unitPrice` is the price for a when you buy it with the quantity of one, the `quantity` is how often you buy the same product and then the `totalPrice` is the `unitPrice` times the `quantity`

As an example say you wanna buy the same product 3 times (that means the `quantity` is 3), one product would cost 12€ as in your example (so the `unitPrice` is 12, that means that the `totalPrice` would be 3x12€ = 36€

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The main thing is the behaviour when it is used in the `order_transaction` context. @dneustadt mad it more clear in another comment.